# WPF - prevent ComboBox from rebinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

Got a bound combobox on a WPF form, and wanted to change the text values on binding without affecting the source object, so I chose to use a converter:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedValuePath="PersonID" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

NoSeedConverter takes in a "Person" object and manipulates the "Name" property to return a string based on other properties of the object.

This works fine when the user is in the form. However, the form is part of a wider MVVM application which loads different form contents into a main window as the user presses navigation buttons. When the user moves away from this form, the Combobox attempts to rebind against an empty source and my Converter throws an error.

In practice this is easily handled with a check inside the Converter code, but it's messy and ugly. There's never any need in practice for this Combobox to ever re-bind after it's loaded. Is there a way I can prevent it from re-binding? I've tried playing with UpdateSourceTrigger, but I can't get it to behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle situations when a value is unavailable for binding.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help, but setting those properties still tries to run the value (empty, in this case) through the Converter.